# Incorrect value is saved to MySQL DB from PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, minute

```
$query="SELECT MINUTE (ETA - STA) 
FROM `FlightSchedule` WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."';";

$delay=ejecutar_query($query);

$query = "UPDATE `FlightSchedule` 
SET `delay`='".$delay."' 
WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."';";

$result=ejecutar_query($query);
```

Instead of saving the minutes values, it saves **Resource id#**. How to fix this issue?

Comment: `$delay` is the resource for the `ejecutar_query` you need to fetch row after this step and insert it in next query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch data using

```
$row = ejecutar_fetch_assoc($delay); // something like that but not sure
```

Modify your update query.

```
$query = "UPDATE `FlightSchedule` 
SET `delay`='".$row['delay']."' 
WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."';";
```

Also modify select query little bit.

```
$query="SELECT MINUTE (ETA - STA) AS delay
FROM `FlightSchedule` WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."';";
```

Comment: Call to undefined function 'ejecutar_fetch_assoc'

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I told you not sure about `fetch_assoc` function.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos You should probably be suggesting to change the method calls to both PDO and prepared statements in your code. They are safer and more reliable - and also you can return them directly as objects in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `$delay` is not the data in the row, but the entire object that represents the results.

You could try to do it in one statement like this however:

```
update `FlightSchedule` set delay=(SELECT MINUTE (ETA - STA) 
FROM `FlightSchedule` WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."');";
```

Edit:

Try this instead to get around the silly lock that MySQL does :)

```
update `FlightSchedule` set delay=(select * from (SELECT MINUTE (ETA - STA) 
FROM `FlightSchedule` WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."'));";
```

Edit 2: (aka I should test my queries rther than just scribbling them off the top of my head...)

```
mysql> select * from updatetest;
+------+------+
| var1 | var2 |
+------+------+
|  450 |    1 |
|  100 |    5 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update
    updatetest set var2=
        (select * from
            (select var2 from updatetest where var1=100)
        updater);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from updatetest;
+------+------+
| var1 | var2 |
+------+------+
|  450 |    5 |
|  100 |    5 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: $query="UPDATE `FlightSchedule` SET delay=(SELECT MINUTE (ETA - STA) FROM `FlightSchedule` WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."') WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."';";
   $result=ejecutar_query($query);
But it does not save anything.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos What does your query show when you echo it out like that? Are you sure that your data for `$flightNum_arr` is properly in the variable?

Comment: Says this: You can't specify target table 'FlightSchedule' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Oh yeah sorry, forgot to wrap it again. See edit.

Comment: Now it says Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Got the statement to work in one. See edit 2 in my answer.